# setting the value of datePicker to a variable

Tags: grails

in Grails 2.3.4 i need to set the value that comes from the datePicker

```
<g:datePicker name="toDate" precision="day"   relativeYears="[0..10]" default="${new Date()}" />
```

to a variable for instance :

```
<g:set var="fromDate" />
```

how can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<g:set />` tag to set the variable value, then assign the variable to the datePicker using the `value` attribute.

```
<g:set var="fromDate" value="${new Date()}" />

<g:datePicker name="toDate" precision="day" value="${fromDate}" />
```

[Here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/datePicker.html) is the documentation.

Comment: thanks, but i want the opposite , that the user chooses a date from datePicker , then the chosen value will be assigned to the variable

Comment: any reply for my question ?